# Powershell - Remove Cell 1,1 from multiple CSV files

Tags: powershell, csv

I've being doing some data collection and in my script there was a boo-boo causing a header to be created when there is no data for it and essentially skewing the results. Now i have 300 CSVs where I need to remove the first header located in cell 1,1 as all the data in the first column is meant for the second header

I was thinking something like the following but i wouldn't know what to put under the "-ExcludeProperty" tag...Let me know if I'm over complicating this

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp *.csv | foreach { $filename=$_.fullname; Import-Csv $filename | select * -ExcludeProperty  |Export-csv $filename.Replace(".csv",".new.csv") -NoTypeInformation }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls C:\temp *.csv | % {
    if ($_ -inotlike '*.new.csv') {
        $header = gc $_ -TotalCount 1
        $header = $header -replace '^[^,]*,', ''
        $rest = gc $_ | select -Skip 1
        $target = $_ -ireplace '\.csv$', '.new.csv'
        $header, $rest | sc $target
    }
}
```

This assumes that Cell 1,1 does not contain a quoted comma. The content of the other cells does not matter.

Comment: Made some modifications as it didn't quite work re-write as follows        
`ls C:\Temp*.csv | % {$header = gc $_ -TotalCount 1
    $headers = $header -replace '^[^,]*,', ''
    $rest = gc $_ | select -Skip 1
    $target = $_ -replace ".csv",".TimeStampRemoved.csv"
    $headers, $rest | sc $target
}`

Comment: For some reason, `-Exclude` doesn't work with `-Include`. I've updated the code.